# allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' error while opening pop up

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I am getting an application level error when opening the pop up window. I have a `try catch` block in my code, but still the error does not get recorded in the database. The error says:

"It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level. This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS"

```
Source Error
<deny Users="*"/>
</authrization>
<authetication mode="Forms">
<forms defaultURL= "~/login.aspx" cookieless="Autodetect"/>
</authetication>

.
```

My application is configured as a virtual directory in IIS. I am not getting this error anywhere in the application except when I open this pop up window. Below is my code to open the pop up window.

```
private void openWindow(int QueryId)
    {
        try
        {
            pnlChart.Visible = true;
            BindBarGraph();
            string strScript = "window.open('/N/Viewer/ViewerSummary.aspx?QueryID=" + QueryId + "', '_blank','height=650, center:yes, width=800, status=no, resizable= yes, menubar=no, toolbar=no, location=yes, scrollbars=no, status=no');";
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "strScript", strScript, true);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

I am getting this error on Windows 2008 server. I am not getting this error when I run the program on my dev machine.

Comment: On the server, have you configured your web site in IIS to be an application?  You local box knows it's a web app but the server doesn't unless IIS is configured correctly

Comment: yes, I did. the whole application is working fine. Its just that pop up window.